# Can't reach nested function from another file in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection, fastify

I am trying to make a layered architecture with nodejs&fastify.

```
import {UserRepository} from "../repositories/UserRepository.js"

const AuthController = (UserRepository) => {
const getUserOne =  () => {
    return "bla"
}

return {getUserOne}
}

export default AuthController
```

I just tried to create a controller which depends on the UserRepository, then I tried to inject this controller into the route file just like this:

```
import AuthController from "../controllers/AuthController.js";
console.log(AuthController.getUser)
export function Auth(f,  opts, done) {
f.post('/register', {}, AuthController.getUserOne )


done()
}
```

But I never reach the getUserOne function from routers, also I saw some similar examples on the web but those didn't help me.

What am I missing actually?

Thank you.

Comment: how are you calling `Auth()`? if it is not reaching the `f.post` call then the problem is in calling `Auth` and not in what you have shown here

Comment: Auth is a route as a fastify plugin and it is registered in the app.  Auth is working, I get error message such like getUserOne is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `AuthController` as function that *returns* an object with the `getUserOne` function as a property. So in order to pass the `getUserOne` function like you are wanting you will need to *call* the `AuthController` function then reference the `getUserOne` function property on the object returned:

```js
import AuthController from "../controllers/AuthController.js";

export function Auth(f,  opts, done) {
  f.post('/register', {}, AuthController().getUserOne )

  done()
}
```

If you are wanting to use the `.`(dot) notation you will need to define the `getUserOne` function as a *property* on the `AuthController` function by using the `this` keyword:

```js
const AuthController = (UserRepository) => {
  this.getUserOne =  () => {
      return "bla"
  }

  return {getUserOne}
}
```

Then you will be able access the `getUserOne` function like you are above

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xb56Jo4V7Ns  In this video, there is a usage without paranthesis, wat am I missing @about14sheep

Comment: he is calling the method, just earlier in the logic. the moment the video starts you will see he is setting the variable `notesDAL` to the return of the call `NotesDAL(fastify.db)` on line 4. You can do the same if you were to do `const authController = AuthController()` first, then you would be able to do `authController.getUserOne`